# How to group by using the prefix of a string i.e. the part before the first space?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, group-by

I have a table with a `varchar` column. The column contains sentences.
How can I group by sentences using their prefixes?
E.g. assume rows like this:

1| Word1 Word2 Word3
2| Word1 Word2 Word3

I want to group by the part of the string *before* the first space.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(columnName,' ',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming DDL**

```
create table test(
  id int,
  value varchar(50)
);
```

**Select Statement**

```
select count(id), substr(value, 1, instr(value, ' '))
from test
group by substr(value, 1, instr(value, ' '));
```

**Working Example** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40ea0/1